# Motorola MC3190 barcode scanner - Require sample code for enabling scanner & load the scan data into textbox using C#.net VS2008

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, motorola-emdk

I'm trying to read the scanned data through my application (C#.net+VS2008) and have to load the data in the textbox of a Window form.

Device Specfication : Motorola MC3190G
OS : Windows CE6.0 / Windows Mobile 6.0
Scanner : Laser LED Type

I'm entirely new to this concept. I require sample code / sample application to proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See the [EMDK FOR .NET V2.8](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=88177) for documentation, code samples and more.